# How to query an attribute on an existing XSLT-FO output node

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to create PDFs from HTML. I want to keep  contents together on rows that do not contain child tables. I have located the appropriate rows but nothing happens, so I logged the output as follows:

```
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <fo:table-row">
      <xsl:if test="count(descendant::table) = 0">
          <xsl:attribute name="keep-together">  
            <xsl:value-of select="always"/>  
          </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:if>
      <xsl:message>
        keep-together = <xsl:value-of select="./@keep-together"/>
      </xsl:message>
```

For each row in the doc, the FOP logging says:

```
keep-together =
```

So, I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
  <fo:table-row keep-together="always">
    <xsl:message>
      keep-together = <xsl:value-of select="./@keep-together"/>
    </xsl:message>
```

This makes jibberish of the output with the nested tables, but in the logging for each table-row it still says:

```
keep-together =
```

So, how does one get the value of a newly-created attribute on a newly-created FO output node?

Comment: Would you not just care what is in the output? Just look in the FO document.

Comment: Kevin, that's a great idea, which, coming from other venues, I have thought of many times. I am using Apache FOP to convert HTML to PDF. The process is direct. I thought I might run it twice to get the styled XML or FO, but FOP seems to be able to unable to create any intermediate output form. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select nodes in the input document, not in the result document. If you store temporary results in a variable then with XSLT 2 or 3 you can also directly select nodes in the variable, or with XSLT 1 you would first need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` on the variable to convert it to a node set and to be able to apply XPath on it.

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="row">
        <fo:table-row>
            <xsl:if test="descendant::table">
                <xsl:attribute name="keep-together">always</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:message select="$row/fo:table-row/@keep-together"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$row"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've never used XSLT before. I've been living on doc sites & stackoverflow for the last week since I started. Could you post something more specific, like some code that I could use for a jump start?

Comment: I hate to sound dumb, but how do you know if you are using XSLT 2 or 3, and if Apache FOP supports them?

Comment: You can use `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` to output the version your used XSLT processor supports. In the Java world the Oracle JRE comes with some version of Xalan Java 2 which is an XSLT 1 processor but you can easily switch to Saxon 9 (available as an open-source version in the HE edition on Sourceforge and Maven) which is an XSLT 2 processor for version 9.7 or earlier and an XSLT 3 processor for version 9.8.

Comment: I have added an example that should work with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor to create the `fo:table-row` in a variable and then output its `keep-together` attribute with `xsl:message`.